# Text gets reversed when written in the search bar input box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I am facing an error.when i write text in `text field`. The text is going in `reverse` order.
for example:

when I write `" Hi how are you "`
The text is going in reverse like this `" UYO REA OH HI "`
how can I fix it? I have used silent WP theme. 
any idea, please?
I have tried to inspect but can no any luck. Can any one guide me?
I also try it. but its not working for me.

```
$('#s').on('keyup', function() {
   var reverse = $(this).val().split('').reverse().join('');
    $('#s').text(reverse);
});
```

Comment: change var reverse = $(this).val().split('').reverse().join(''); to var reverse = $(this).val().split('').join('');

Comment: Not working sir... @Dean219

Comment: I just copied the code and tested it and the output was in reverse for the original and regular without the reverse method being called..have you tried clearing your browser history settings etc to make sure the scripts etc werent cached locally and changes are view-able? Since there really is no other reason for the text to be reversed other than the reverse method....since your statement takes a string, converts it to an array and then reverses the order of that array and joins it back into the original string and prints it.....

Comment: Maybe try removing the entire thing if you dont want it in reverse too... var reverse = $(this).val();  $('#s').text(reverse);

Comment: it because of autocomplete, when you write some think it call every time so your function not work. open console and check you get this url call - http://symfoni-esm.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?callback=jQuery1111021629262803573623_1472645533593&action=myprefix_autocompletesearch&term=sttestted&_=1472645533605

Comment: actually i have remove autocomplete file. now check again. there is no single error in console. but still not working :(

Answer (score 1):

What about CSS? Maybe that will help:

```
    direction: rtl;
    unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
```